# Termination of position before starting

Tags: united-states, termination, legal

I accepted and signed a contract to be a nanny for 2 months in Chicago.  Today I was informed that they will be staying in Cleveland and will not need my services.

These two items were in my contract.  Does this let them off scott free?

> Notwithstanding any other term or condition expressed or implied in
>   this Agreement, in the event that the Employer will discontinue
>   operating its business at the location where the Employee is employed,
>   then, at the Employer’s sole option, and as permitted by law, this
>   Agreement will terminate as of the last day of the month in which the
>   Employer ceases operations at such location with the same force and
>   effect as if such last day of the month were originally set as the
>   Termination Date of this Agreement. The Employee and the Employer
>   agree that reasonable and sufficient notice of termination of
>   employment by the Employer is the greater of two (2) weeks or any
>   minimum notice required by law.

Comment: This is a classic Contract Law 101 question.  As such, you would have to consult an attorney (solicitor in the UK) who is familiar with the law in your jurisdiction.  At best, you would be entitled to "the greater of two (2) weeks or any minimum notice required by law", which would be offset by whatever you had to pay an attorney to extract it forcibly from them.  Your best bet is likely going to be to write this one off as a tuition payment to the school of hard knocks.

Comment: Is the contract signed by both parties? If so, they are legally obligated to follow the termination terms. The question now is whether it is worth your time and money to enforce it?